# What is the best practice to duplicate mysql data and hide else where

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm dealing with a website that holds a lot of user data which is all stored in one database (MySQL using PHP).

I would like to reduce the risk of possibly losing these large sums of data and I was thinking that its silly to have it in all one place (one DB). If the current tables get dropped or hacked, the website could lose all the data obtained over years of hard work. Not to mention losing/exposing sensitive user info.

I was wondering if someone could propose a decent practice to hide data somewhere else.

I've read some articles that introduce the concept but they don't talk about best practice etc.

I was thinking of making a secondary database that is used to hide the records in it but it still seems unreasonable because if one database gets hacked, what stops the other from being exposed at the same time.

Also would it be rational to hash all the data that is stored? I'm talking about things like hashing out names, emails, etc in php before inserting into second database.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: I would suggest two ways : 1. Either use two servers to save your data, so if one server got hacked your data will be safe on another database. OR 2. You can clone your database and take actual database's update on regular basis, so if somebody hacks/deletes your database, you could have test database copy.

Comment: 1) If php code and DB server are running on the same host nothing will prevent data loss or data exposure when server is hacked. 2) Regular DB backups or mirroring to safe place elsewhere prevents data loss but not data exposure. 3) If you move DB to safer separate backend server it will reduce attack surface. 4) Data encryption/decryption can be done natively and  completely inside mysql, with or without triggers. 5) If you don't always need ALL user data in web frontend consider moving most of it to a separate archive db on a safe server.